# Filter list in between minprice and maxprice in mvc4

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Filter part in my project. I am having problem to filter the list of item that falls in between Min price and Max price. I don't know what i have done wrong.

[image]

```
public ActionResult FilteredResult(string Location, string Type, string Category, string MinValue, string MaxValue, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string CurrentPageNumber)
        {

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            var sdata = currentFilter;
            if (sdata == null)
            {
                ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Location + "/" + Type  + "/" + Category  + "/" + MinValue + "/" + MaxValue;
            }else
            {
                ViewBag.CurrentFilter = sdata;
                var data = sdata.Split('/');
                Location = data[0] == "" ? "" : data[0];
                Type = data[1] == "" ? "" : data[1];
                Category = data[2] == "" ? "" : data[2];
                MinValue = data[3] == "" ? "" : data[3];
                MaxValue = data[4] == "" ? "" : data[4];
            }

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            List<ListingItem> FilteredListing = new List<ListingItem>();
            var Property = from s in db.RE_PropertyDetails
                           where (s.IsActive == true)
                           select s;
            var PropertPaginate = from s in db.RE_PropertyDetails
                                  where (s.IsActive == true)
                                  select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {

                Property = Property.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper()));
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper()));
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {

                var typ = Convert.ToInt32(Type);
                Property = Property.Where(s => s.TypeId == typ);
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.TypeId == typ);

            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {
                var cat = Convert.ToInt32(Category);

                Property = Property.Where(s => s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);

            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {
                var cat = Convert.ToInt32(Category);

                Property = Property.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper())
                                  && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper())
                                  && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);

            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {

                var typ = Convert.ToInt32(Type);
                Property = Property.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper()) && s.TypeId == typ);
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper()) && s.TypeId == typ);
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {
                var cat = Convert.ToInt32(Category);
                var typ = Convert.ToInt32(Type);
                Property = Property.Where(s => s.TypeId == typ
                                  && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);
                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.TypeId == typ
                                 && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat);

            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Type) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Category))
            {
                var cat = Convert.ToInt32(Category);
                var typ = Convert.ToInt32(Type);
                Property = Property.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper())
                                  && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat
                                  && s.TypeId == typ);

                PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.Where(s => s.Location.ToUpper().Contains(Location.ToUpper())
                                 && s.PropertyCategoryId == cat
                                  && s.TypeId == typ);

            }
            else
            {

            }

            var maxval = Convert.ToDecimal(MaxValue);
            var minval = Convert.ToDecimal(MinValue);
            var otherproperty = Property.Where(s => s.Price >= minval && s.Price <= maxval).OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            Property = otherproperty;
            var otherPropertPaginate = Property.Where(s => s.Price >= minval && s.Price <= maxval).OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            PropertPaginate = otherPropertPaginate;



            foreach (var item in Property)
            {
                ListingItem obj = new ListingItem();

                obj.PropertyID = item.PropertyID;
                obj.PropertName = item.PropertName;
                obj.ImageId = db.RE_ImageDetail.Where(p => p.PropertyId == item.PropertyID).Select(p => p.ImageId).FirstOrDefault();
                obj.ImageName = db.RE_ImageDetail.Where(p => p.PropertyId == item.PropertyID).Select(p => p.ImageName).FirstOrDefault();
                obj.ParkingArea = item.ParkingArea;
                obj.BedRoom = item.BedRoom;
                obj.BathRoom = item.BathRoom;
                obj.LivingRoom = item.LivingRoom;
                obj.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Price);
                obj.Area = item.Area.ToString();
                FilteredListing.Add(obj);
            }
            ViewBag.FilterListing = FilteredListing;
            ViewBag.CountedNumber = Property.Count();

            var Maxvalue = db.RE_PropertyDetails.Select(o => o.Price).Max();
            ViewBag.MaxPrice = Maxvalue;
            var Minvalue = db.RE_PropertyDetails.Select(o => o.Price).Min();
            ViewBag.Minvalue = Minvalue;



            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Date: Ascending":
                    PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.OrderBy(s => s.AddedonDate);
                    break;
                case "Date: Descending":
                    PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.OrderByDescending(s => s.AddedonDate);
                    break;
                case "Price: Lowest First":
                    PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.OrderBy(s => s.Price.HasValue);
                    break;
                case "Price: Highest First":
                    PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price.HasValue);
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    PropertPaginate = PropertPaginate.OrderBy(s => s.PropertName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPageNumber == null ? "10" : CurrentPageNumber);
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            ViewBag.page = page == null ? 1 : pageNumber;
            return View(PropertPaginate.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

        }
```

I am getting the min and max value as string, Then i wrote the code

```
var maxval = Convert.ToDecimal(MaxValue);
            var minval = Convert.ToDecimal(MinValue);
            var otherproperty = Property.Where(s => s.Price >= minval && s.Price <= maxval).OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            Property = otherproperty;
```

But it is yielding data  which is not inside the bounderies of min and max price. sometimes it yields no data or sometime if the max value is bit increasing it shows 4-5 data.

for example 
there is data with price 11,200000,500000,.....
when minvalue = 10 and maxvalue=20191023
As you can see it is showing no data

when minvalue = 10 and maxvalue = 400000
it will show data upto 500000

Can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Why in the world are you making your parameters `string` when most are clearly `int?` or `decimal?` etc (and then having to convert them). And change all your code to simply do `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Location) { ... }; if (typ.HasValue) { ... }; if (cat.HasValue) { ... };` etc

Comment: I have made the changes as you have suggested but about the item in between the price range is not shown can you review my code  


``
var maxval = Convert.ToDecimal(MaxValue);
            var minval = Convert.ToDecimal(MinValue);
            var otherproperty = Property.Where(s => s.Price >= minval && s.Price <= maxval).OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            Property = otherproperty;
            var otherPropertPaginate = Property.Where(s => s.Price >= minval && s.Price <= maxval).OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            PropertPaginate = otherPropertPaginate;
``

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but nothing in your code makes any sense. Your posting back values which are bound to your parameters, then you ignore them and overwrite them with values from your `currentFilter` parameter which are clearly not the same values that your posting and therefore you results will not be correct. And why in the world are you creating 2 identical collections (`Property` and `PropertPaginate`)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using the `string`, It's clearly needs to have a `int` or `decimal` values.

```
public ActionResult FilteredResult(string Location, string Type, string Category, decimal? MinValue, decimal? MaxValue, int sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string CurrentPageNumber)
{
   // Your stuff..
}
```